# How to include a Custom social plugin inside Facebook's Photos app on Facebook.com

Tags: facebook

Is there a way I can "add" my custom social plugin say "iTag2" into Facebook's Photos app ?

that "iTag2" does something slightly different to Facebook's "Tag This Photo" plugin.

in other words, does Facebook Photos App allow another app to be a "plugin" of some sort ?

Answer (score 0):

No, it's not possible to insert your code onto arbitrary pages on Facebook.com